# mechanism in formulation of mesylates and tosylates

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

[image]

in these reaction(Ts and Ms), why do they proceed in different mechanism/?

more specifically,

1. (Ts) e- pair from O attacks S, (Ms)but not in latter reaction. why?

it makes no sense. because TsCl is more sterically hindered by benzene ring.

2. in Ms, e- from hydroxyl group attack H attached to methyl group instead. I'm not famillar with H that was attached to C taken by other things. 
   strong base can do this?

help me~

Comment: Don't post the same question twice. Edit your previous question if you want to add more information.

Comment: okay. sorry T_T